TLMGR retry in a different mirror
I'm using TLMGR to build the docker image for my project. Sometimes, the command TLMGR is crashing due to an issue in the CTAN mirror.
In my case, I was getting the following error:
/opt/texlive/texdir/bin/default/tlmgr: main database at https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb is not signed: no access to cryptographic signature

For this kind of error I would like to allow TLMGR to retry the installation using a different mirror. This would avoid the command to crash due to reasons that I don't have control.
Is there any option I could use on TLMGR to enable multiple retries on different CTAN mirrors?

I don't think tlmgr has an option but you can use the --repository option to specify a different mirror and instead of calling tlmgr explicitly call a script with some list of mirrors and try another one if you get an access error

You can configure multiple mirrors but, as far as I could figure, it only ever tries one. I'd recommend using a script before calling tlmgr so you can find not just a 'working' mirror but one which is not glacially slow. Something like reflector for Arch Linux.
